# Jmeter: JSON response manipulation and passing to the next http request

Tags: json, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

I've got the response from HTTP GET request as JSON file and I want to use that JSON and pass it to the next HTTP request. I got the following response data

```
{
  "apiInfo": {
      "id": "23143",
      "name": "bookkeeping",
      "state": "used",
      "data": "15893712000000"
  },
  "apiDetails": [
     {
        "bookName": "abc",
        "state": "old",
        "noOfTimesUsed": "53"
        "additionalParam"{
            "name": "abc",
            "id": "123"
        }
    },
    {
        "bookName": "def",
        "state": "new",
        "noOfTimesUsed": "5",
        "action": "keep"
        "additionalParam"{
            "name": "def",
            "id": "456"
        }
    },
    {
        "bookName": "xyz",
        "state": "avg",
        "noOfTimesUsed": "23"
        "additionalParam"{
            "name": "ghi",
            "id": "789"
        }
    },
    {
        "bookName": "pqr",
        "state": "old",
        "noOfTimesUsed": "75",
        "action": "discard"
        "additionalParam"{
            "name": "jkl",
            "id": "012"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use "apiInfo" & "apiDetails" part from the JSON response and manipulate its data. As you can notice, some array field have attribute "action" in it and some one doesn't. I want to make sure all the field in the array have this data and is assigned as ' "action":"keep" '. Also, I want to add "id" from apiInfo & "name" from additionalParams from apiDetails itself. The end result I want is somewhat like this

```
"apiDetails": [
   {
      "id": "23143",
      "bookName": "abc",
      "state": "old",
      "noOfTimesUsed": "53",
      "action": "keep",
      "name":"abc"
   },
   {
       "id": "23143",
       "bookName": "def",
       "state": "new",
       "noOfTimesUsed": "5",
       "action": "keep",
      "name":"def"
   },
   { 
       "id": "23143",
       "bookName": "xyz",
       "state": "avg",
       "noOfTimesUsed": "23",
       "action": "keep",
      "name":"ghi"
   },
   {
       "id": "23143",
       "bookName": "pqr",
       "state": "old",
       "noOfTimesUsed": "75",
       "action": "keep",
      "name":"jkl"
    }
  ]
```

I've been trying to use JSR223 sampler and have been struggling with it. It's bit complicated and I need help. P.S.: I've tried using javascript code to manipulate the results as desired but have been unsuccessful.

Please help.

Thanks,  Sid

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def apiDetails = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).apiDetails

   apiDetails.each { apiDetail ->
       apiDetail.put('action', 'keep')
   }

   vars.put('request', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(apidetails: apiDetails.collect()).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, you should be able to refer the generated request as `${request}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited the question and now I'm stuck with nested JSON and extracting and putting from different JSON block. Please help.